# C++ Simple cout ostream

Tags: c++, cout, ostream

```
#include"MyString.h"
#include<iostream>
    MyString::MyString()//default constructor
    {
        length=0;
        data=NULL;
        cout<<"Default called by right none is called"<<endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    MyString::MyString(char *source)//cstyle string parameter
    {
        int counter=0;
        //we implement count without using getlen
        for(int i=0;(source[i])!='\0';i++)//assume their char string is terminated by null
        {
            counter++;
        }
        length=counter;
        cout<<"THE LENGTH of "<<source<<" is "<<counter<<endl;
        system("pause");
        data = new char[length];
    }
    void MyString::print(ostream a)//what to put in besides ostream
    {
        a<<data;
    }
```

the above  is in my implementation file

This is in my main file

```
 int main()
 {
    MyString s1("abcd");// constructor with cstyle style array
    s1.print(cout);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
 }
```

Why cant this work?
Im getting this error

error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'

Million Thanks! ERROR FIXED!!

Comment: Not sure why that's not working (without looking in detail) but you may want to consider implementing I/O on your class the same way 99.9999% of C++ coders do. By that, I mean with `operator<<` rather than half coding in C++ and half in C :-)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make a copy of `std::cout`, `std::cin`, `std::cerr`, or any other object derived from `std::ios_base` since the copy-constructor for that object is private ... you must pass all stream objects derived from `ios_base` by reference in order to prevent invocation of the copy-constructor. Thus your function signature:

```
void MyString::print(ostream a);
```

needs to at least change to

```
void MyString::print(ostream& a);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the call to `print` tries to copy the output stream, which is not allowed. You have change the function to take the argument as a reference:

```
void MyString::print(ostream &a)
```